# Return Key not Changing in IB or Code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, interface-builder

Pulling my hair out with this one. Using xCode 8.2.1 and trying to change the "Return Key" on the keyboard.

Tried:

1. Setting it via the Interface Builder:
   [image]
2. Via Code:

> ```
> @IBOutlet var password : UITextField?
>
> override open func viewDidLoad() {
>      password?.returnKeyType = .next
>      password?.reloadInputViews()
>   }
> ```

I can confirm the IBOutlet `password` is also set.

This happens on every Storyboard View I have in the app, nothing is changing the keyboard setting.

Same result on Simulator and on a Device.

[image]

Comment: `password` is what? A `UITextField`?

Comment: Correct. Sorry I added the @IBoutlet to show this.

Comment: What result are you hoping for / expecting?

Comment: Is `password` nil at `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: It's set on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I want the Keyboard to show `Next` or `Done` in the bottom right corner @matt

Answer (score 0):

I can show that it *does* work. I did this:

[image]

And I got this (note the key at the lower right):

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it does work on a fresh instance, something must be stopping it :(

Comment: Fine. But your question gave no information about what that might be, so only you can search for it. Outside of your computer the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: Are you sure it's just on my computer? Potentially someone in the world had the same issue to find a toggle, or setting, or something that was causing the same thing to happen. Isn't that what StackOverflow is about?